# JavaScript form into PHP table

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I am creating a website. On one of the pages there is a JavaScript form that asks for the usual information: Name, email etc and then I need to save it into a table using MYSQL and then I want to display the table using PHP on another page. I have no idea how to start saving the data into a table (when Submit is hit) and then displaying the table on another page. Any advice?

Comment: I'm afraid you need to learn MySQL and PHP, sorry.

Comment: lack of knowledge on the programming languages in hand, I suggest you start trying out simple things in PHP first before implementing MySQL

Comment: What is a "JAvaScript form" anyway?

Comment: please show your javascript form

Answer (score -1):

http://teamtutorials.com/web-development-tutorials/php-tutorials/inserting-data-into-a-mysql-database-using-php#.T5rIZLNWq9Q

Comment: -1: Link to poor tutorial (SQL injection vulnerability, use of mysql_* extension)

Comment: Interesting down votes. I think you miss the audience--the poster is obviously new and the linked article demonstrates the relationship between html, php and mysql using his own problem statement.

I certainly didn't write my first "Hello"+"World" with a StringBuilder.

Comment: The poster being new is surely all the more reason not to teach bad practices. The tutorial linked really is not something that should be shown to newbies! Recommending mysql_* is one thing, but it doesn't even pay lip service to sql injection as a concern.